# AngularJS - ngView and "keep in memory"

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

I use AngularJS and ngView in my project.

ngView works perfectly with ngRoute, but when I come back to the previus link, ngView reload again data (with Ajax).

Is it possible to "keep in memory" previus data, so that should not always recharge all?

Comment: Why you don't save your data in Data Storage of the Browser? and retrieve them when reload ng-view!

Comment: do you make ajax requests with $http?

Comment: You could use a service to retrieve your data, and cache that data inside the service.

Comment: @NrNazifi yes, but I was thinking of using some kind of cache..

Comment: @MajoB not always, because somethimes I other script to create new element (after Ajax request)

Comment: @jlowcs which service? How?

Comment: You can create your own service: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: `$http` also provides cache option. Question is too broad for real solutions

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, my fault. I don't want to use the cache of $http. I would that the ngRoute doesn't reload the ngView content when I come back, but I would that the ngRoute use the previus content..

Comment: You would need to store in service then

Answer (score 0):

You should store your data in localStorage (or cookieStorage if localStorage is not available), and manage your own cache policy. Then check in your controller if the data is Available and not expired before showing it up. I always use a service of my own that goes like:

```
(function () {

var __service = function () {

    var __set = function (key, item) { localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item)); };
    var __get = function (key) { return (localStorage.getItem(key) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) : null); };
    var __clear = function (key) { localStorage.removeItem(key); };
    var __clearAll = function () { localStorage.clear(); };

    return {
        Set: __set,
        Get: __get,
        Clear: __clear,
        ClearAll: __clearAll
    };

};
angular.module('myApp').service('StorageService', __service);

}());
```

Then in my controllers I put that service to work in order to cache information that I do not want to retrieve everytime I get there.

PD: I know i must specialize that service to check if localStorage is available.

Comment: Thanks. I should to do something like the facebook app notifications: when I click on a notification a go on a page and when I go back, I come back on notification tab at same point.. Maybe I can't explain well, is it possibile to do this: http://it.tinypic.com/r/711gsz/8 ? Your code works for this?

Comment: Sorry, i really really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to save the ViewState of your page ? remember that angular works on a SPA (Single Page Application) philosophy, therefore handling back button actions is somewhat tricky.

Comment: I would that when the user comes back, he sees the previous page exactly as he had left